# Can I have 3 elements in a dictionary

Tags: python

So if I have 2 dictionarys..

```
opt1 = {"A" : 1,
        "B" : 1,
        "C" : 1,
}
opt2 = {"A" : "b",
        "B" : "n",
        "C" : "m",
}
```

Other than making a dictionary of lists, is there anyway I could make this into 1 dictionary? so it would be something like.. (I know this doesn't work though..)

```
opt = {"A" : 1 : "b",
       "B" : 2 : "n",
       "C" : 3 : "m",
    }
```

Comment: dictionary of (`lists`, `tuples`, or `sets`) are your options

Comment: A dictionary maps keys to values. `"A"` is the key, `1` is the value. If you want the value to hold more than one element, use a container type: `{'A': [1, 2]}`, `{'A': (1, 2)}`, etc.

Comment: How would I reference the 1 or 2 depending on which one i want?

Comment: `opt['A'][0]` for 1, `opt['A'][1]` for 2

Comment: `{k: [opt1.get(k), opt2.get(k)] for k in opt1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like this: (tuples as values) as in:

```
opt1_2 = {"A" : (1,"b"), 
          "B" : (1,"n"), 
          "C" : (1,"m"), 
         }
```

Here's a very basic way to do that

```
opt2_2 = {key:(opt1[key], opt2[key]) for key in opt1.keys()}
```

This assumes that the key sets are identical (or at least that all keys of 1 are also keys of 2, and you don't care about keys of 2 that aren't in 1. A more complex comprehension will catch that, but I'll keep it simple here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a defaultdict with a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for opt in (opt1, opt2,):
    d.update(opt)
```

You can add as many items as you like.

You could also use a defaultdict(set) if you want fast test of existance of a value, no duplicate values and you don't need to keep the order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
opt1 = {"A" : 1,
        "B" : 1,
        "C" : 1,
}
opt2 = {"A" : "b",
        "B" : "n",
        "C" : "m",
}

answer = {}
for d in [opt1, opt2]:
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if k not in answer:
            answer[k] = []
        answer[k].append(v)
```

Comment: @downvoter: would you like to tell me why this is a particularly bad answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead:

```
opt = {}
for i in opt1:
    opt[i] = [opt1[i], opt2[i]]
```

This way, `opt` will have the value `{'A': [1, 'b'], 'C': [1, 'm'], 'B': [1, 'n']}`.
It's not possible to make a dictionary like this:

```
opt = {"A" : 1 : "b",
       "B" : 2 : "n",
       "C" : 3 : "m",
    }
```